# os.system Runs Shell Command Before Previous Lines Of My Code

Tags: python, os.system

I have a code like this:

```
x = datetime.datetime.now()
with open ("lutfen_ol.log", 'a') as logluyoruz:
    logluyoruz.write("Islemler baslatiliyor.#####" + str(x) + "\n")
    os.system("stat log_deneme | grep Modify >> lutfen_ol.log")
    logluyoruz.write("\n")
```

I'm using this code for have a output like this:

```
Islemler baslatiliyor.#####2021-02-06 20:23:13.995523
Modify: 2021-02-06 20:24:43.000959580 -0500
```

But it returns a result like this:

```
Modify: 2021-02-06 20:23:08.056955577 -0500
Islemler baslatiliyor.#####2021-02-06 20:23:13.995523
```

How can I get a result like what I want?
os.system line is after writing "Islem baslatiliyor.#####" to my log file but it runs before this..

I tried to sleep my code before get stat of the "log_deneme" file's but it's not working. Still running before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it guys..

```
with open ("lutfen_ol.log", 'a') as logluyoruz:
    logluyoruz.write("Islemler baslatiliyor.#####" + str(x) + "\n")
    logluyoruz.write("\n")

os.system("stat log_deneme | grep Modify >> lutfen_ol.log")
```

I tried this code and it worked. I think the code in my question is not working like what I expected because it's in tab of `with open`.

So it's answer of my question but not completely explaining source of the problem. It's only my guess.

Thank you everyone.